# Is layover time 1.5 hours in Dubai is long enough for connection to Hyderabad

Tags: layovers, dxb, short-connections

I'm plannning to travel with the family of 3 persons from JFK to Hyderabad with 1.5 Hours of the layover in Dubai, all are Emirates. I'm wondering can I make my connection to Hyderabad. Any possible delays please suggest.

Comment: Under what consideration let you think that you will delay?

Comment: Is your ticket on a single booking?

Comment: For the physical connection, I've done Emirates from the states to India with a 90 minute layover no problem.  That's just anecdotal, so I'm not putting it as an answer.

Comment: As a notes, I have flown on emirates from London via Dubai to Hyderabad a couple of times in the past - and 90 minutes was definitely enough.  That said, I was flying business class, therefore could often go through express lanes.